# Modal width (increase)

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I want a modal to be 80% or so of a screen width. `modal-lg` isn't large enough. This:

```
.modal .modal-dialog {
  width: 80%;
}
```

Doesn't work with Bootstrap 4.

Comment: In bootstrap 3 I just use `modal-lg` and `modal-sm` classes to have large and small modals. You can also overrite the `.modal-lg` in your css.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

**Bootstrap 3**

You can create or just override default bootstrap `modal-lg`by doing below:

```
.modal-lg {
    max-width: 80%;
}
```

If not working just add `!important` so it would look like below

```
.modal-lg {
    max-width: 80% !important;
}
```

Now call the `modal-lg`.

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
 <!-- some modal content --->
</div
```

> For **Bootstrap 4** refer to @kitsu.eb answer. Also note that using bootstrap 4 utilities might break the responsiveness.

Answer (score 115):

Bootstrap 4 includes [sizing utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/sizing/). You can change the size to 25/50/75/100% of the page width (I wish there were even more increments).

To use these we will replace the `modal-lg` class. Both the default width and `modal-lg` use css `max-width` to control the modal's width, so first add the `mw-100` class to effectively disable `max-width`. Then just add the width class you want, e.g. `w-75`.

Note that you should place the `mw-100` and `w-75` classes in the div with the `modal-dialog` class, not the `modal` div e.g.,

```
<div class='modal-dialog mw-100 w-75'>
    ...
</div>
```

Also, we can even use the well known `container` class (instead of specifying the size), like:

```html
<div class="modal-dialog mw-100">
    <div class="modal-content container">
        <div class="modal-body">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the real answer.

Comment: But is this responsive? I changed for a modal window, but for the mobile window it's retaining the class. a modal-lg won't do that i think

Comment: @AlanPallath Any use of the width classes potentially breaks responsiveness. There was a proposal for responsive width classes (ex. `w-lg-100`), but the bootstrap maintainers didn't want to add them.

Comment: Yea, I thought so. Hence a `@media (min-width: 992px)` helped me solve the issue instead of this one. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This fails on small (xs) screens

Answer (score 27):

For responsive answer.

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .modal-dialog {
    max-width: 80%;
  }
}
```

Comment: this is correct answer, answer from kitsu.eb breaks the modal in xs sizes, thanks @Joel

Answer (score 9):

In Bootstrap 4 you have to use 'max-width' attribute and then it works perfectly.

```
<div id="modal_dialog" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display: none;">
<div class="modal-dialog" style="max-width: 1350px!important;" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            Sample text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply Use !important after giving width of that class that is override your class.

**For Example**

```
.modal .modal-dialog {
  width: 850px !important;
}
```

Hopefully this will works for you.

Comment: it is working but is not responsive, for iPhone it is not working

Answer (score 3):

This was the solution that worked for me:

```css
.modal{
 padding: 0 !important;
}
.modal-dialog {
  max-width: 80% !important;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.modal-content {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a href="#" class="menu-toggler" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">Menu</a>

<div class="modal mobile-nav-modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <a href="#" class="" data-dismiss="modal">Close Menu</a>

      <nav class="modal-nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button">Shop</a>
            <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List 3</a></li>
              </ul>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List 3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Made To Order</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Heritage</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Style & Fit</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

try to use px

```
.modal .modal-dialog {
  width: 850px;
}
```

just change the size.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your modal is not placed in a container, try to add the !important annotation if it's not changing the width from the original one.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Sass,

according to the [documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/options/) you can customize your default values.

In your case, you can easily override the variable named `$modal-lg` in your `_custom.scss` file.

Answer (score 1):

```
The following solution will work for Bootstrap 4.

.modal .modal-dialog {
  max-width: 850px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, This was the solution that worked for me:

```
<div class="modal-dialog" style="min-width: 1500px" role="document">
```

Answer (score 0):

So i have been struggling too  on the same issue. The quick and easiest way to solve the problem is by just adding

1. `modal-lg` on your modal Div

Example `<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">`

Answer (score 0):

Set `max-width:80%;` as an inline stylesheet

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document" style="max-width: 80%;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of absolute and relative units

```
.modal-dialog-xw {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  min-width: 330px;    /* To prevent shrinking of very small screens (Galaxy S9 for example) */
  max-width: 75%;      /* To use 75% of the width available. Or set in pixels if need. */
}
```

In html code add after .modal-dialog

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-xw" role="document">...</div>
```