# Modal width inline CSS bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

I need to customize the width of the modal (need to make it larger than `modal-xl`)

My approach is as follows however, it does not seem to be working.

```
<div class="modal"  id="creditNoteDetailsModal" *ngIf="creditNoteDetails" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" style="width: 1400px" role="document">
....
....
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your css

```
   .modal-xl{    
    max-width:80%;    
    }
```

If not working just add !important so it would look like below

```
.modal-xl {
    max-width: 80% !important;
}
```

And call the modal-xl.

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-xl modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
 <!-- some model content --->
</div>
```

or set stylesheet as below

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-xl modal-dialog-centered" role="document" style="max-width: 80%;">
```

Refer -> [Modal width (increase)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42896820/modal-width-increase)